# javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator and Allocation Size

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

We all know the default behavior of Hibernate when using @SequenceGenerator - it increases real database sequence by one, multiple this value by 50 (default allocation Size value) - and then uses this value as entity ID. So the first questions is why the hibernate multiplies the sequence number fetched from database with allocation size ?????

Second how to get rid of constraint violation exception in case when Spring/Hibernate application and ETL job is inserting the data in same table at the same time ?

Also the huge gap in sequence values in table are seen, what is the solution for this also.

Just for reference we are using following annotation in application to generated the values of primary key column using sequence defined in Oracle database :

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seqGenerator", sequenceName = "SEQ_table1")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seqGenerator")
private Long id;
```